# Catkin_make fails due to Bzip2 libraries on Raspberry Pi

Tags: rosbag, catkin, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using Ros Indigo installed on a Raspberry Pi model B. When I run catkin_make I get an error during the compilation of RosBag-storage package.  The BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR are missing.

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosbag_storage'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/rosbag_storage)
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):   Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR) Call Stack (most recent call first):   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBZip2.cmake:47 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)   ros_comm/rosbag_storage/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! Invoking "cmake" failed
```

How can I add these libraries?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215914/catkin_make-fails-due-to-bzip2-libraries-on-raspberry-pi/) by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2015-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just install libbz2-dev package with:

`sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev`

This package contains the header files required to compile your rosbag_storage.

---

Originally posted by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) with karma: 98 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1